# Migrating Python3.7 Flask website to Ubuntu with Webuzo

Tags: php, codeigniter, mysqli

Migrating Python2.7 Flask web site to Ubuntu with Webuzo

```
Message: mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'Web_matrimony'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Filename: mysqli/mysqli_driver.php

Line Number: 202
```

Comment: You can re edit your question by clicking on the edit button below tags rather than putting all that code in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

If this is hosted on godaddy then you will need to add the godaddy hostname for your DB.  I recommend adding another db config for production.